# React-Native - Keyboard Up and Down Feature

Tags: reactjs, react-native, keyboard

I want to move the screen up when keyboard up and screen down when keyboard down in React- Native. please provide any library or help.

Answer (score 2):

You Can read about it in the [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html)

Basically you need to embed all your screen containing the inputs inside a `KeyboardAvoidingView` rather than a traditionnal `View`

Comment: Which is pretty buggy actually, esp when using navigation headers and footers

Answer (score 0):

I use following package [react-native-keyboard-spacer](https://github.com/Andr3wHur5t/react-native-keyboard-spacer) and so far it is working for me.